# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65

Tags: java

I have this basic-Java-code:

```
class Rueda {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String frase[] = {"TODA CUESTION TIENE DOS PUNTOS DE VISTA", "EL EQUIVOCADO Y EL NUESTRO",
        "TODAS LAS MUJERES TIENEN ALGO HERMOSO", "AUNQUE SEA UNA PRIMA LEJANA",
        "SE ESTA MURIENDO GENTE", "HE OIDO HABLAR TAN BIEN DE TI", "QUE CREIA QUE ESTABAS MUERTO",
        "RECUERDA SIEMPRE QUE ERES UNICO", "EXACTAMENTE IGUAL QUE TODOS LOS DEMAS",
        "TODO TIEMPO PASADO FUE ANTERIOR"};
    int[] contadorLetras = new int[26];
    for (int contador = 0; contador < frase.length; contador++) {
        String current = frase[contador];
        char[] letras = current.toCharArray();
        for (int contador2 = 0; contador2 < letras.length; contador2++) {
            char let = letras[contador2];
            if ((let >= 'A') & (let <= 'Z')) {
                contadorLetras[let='A']++;
            }

        }
        for (char contador3 = 'A'; contador3 < 'Z'; contador3++) {
            System.out.print(contador3 + ": " + contadorLetras[contador3  - 'A'] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

And, when I try to run it, I get this error message:

`run:` Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65

And, as you can guess, I am not able to find the error. But, please, instead of showing me directly the problem, could you please tell me why am I getting this message? Does it have something to do with the spaces?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `contadorLetras[let='A']` not a good idea. How about `contadorLetras[let - 'A']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a typographical error. `contadorLetras[let='A']`. Do you know what the int value of `'A'` is?

Hint: your exception stacktrace is telling you:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **65**

This means that your code above shows that you're trying to access `contadorLetras['A']` which is the same as `contadorLetras[65]` which goes well beyond the range of your array.

Instead, get rid of the `=` and change it to a `-`, since `let - 'A'` is what you want:

```
contadorLetras[let - 'A']++:
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace

```
        if ((let >= 'A') & (let <= 'Z')) {
            contadorLetras[let='A']++;
        }
```

for

```
        if ((let >= 'A') & (let <= 'Z')) {
            contadorLetras[let - 'A' ]++;
        }
```